# Checking React defaultProps with Flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types

I've been looking to add Flow to my React project, but I'm unclear as to how to type check defaultProps.

Let's say I have a very basic component:

```
const React = require('react')

type MyComponentProps = {
  example: string
}

const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => <span>{props.example}</span>

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  example: 1,
}
```

Here the default value for the **example** prop is an integer, and even though I'm declaring that it should be a string, Flow reports: `No errors!`

If I add the following:

```
let component = <MyComponent />
```

Flow throws this error, as I would expect:

```
13: let component = <MyComponent />
                     ^ props of React element `MyComponent`.
                       This type is incompatible with
7: const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => <span>{props.example}</span>
                                 ^ object type

Property `example` is incompatible:
10:   example: 1,
               ^ number. This type is incompatible with
4:   example: string
               ^ string
```

Is this expected behaviour?

Can I get Flow to check defaultProps without having to call the component itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set default props using the destructured props syntax, you'll get the error

```
const React = require('react')

type MyComponentProps = {
  example: string
}

const MyComponent = ({ example = 1}: MyComponentProps) => <span>{example}</span>
```

here's [an example](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBASgUwIbFgXhgJwQRwK4CW2AFAOTYpSkCUAULVAJ4AOCMAsowMIgC2z4BGCgAFTCGYQYGAN60YMBAA8k-ADYIAXDGiYCYAOa0AvvVCRYnHv0HDpMYjMUr1bDAEZj2q3wFghouKS1NIAfDAAPBDMSGChMsqqzBrGEQD00bGhtEA)

alternatively, you could do:

```
const React = require('react')

type MyComponentProps = {
  example: string
}

const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => <span>{props.example}</span>

const defaultProps: MyComponentProps = {
  example: 1,
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = defaultProps
```